# Threading multiple async calls to WCF Services

Tags: multithreading, wcf, model-view-controller

I need to call multiple Wcf services in async, at the moment I am daisey changing them and its too slow, i need to call them all at once then get the complete data into a BO.

I have the following code below, which calls then same method on complete, but as you can see there are problems with the threads calling the same method, it calls the method 25 times when it should only be 5.

In a previous example it showed a sepe

Could you please tell me how to lock the method so only one thread can use it at a time, also is it valid to use the BackgroundWorkerProcess in my class which is part of a MVC 2 application?

```
namespace WCFThreadingTest
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int result = 0;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Completed += (s, a) =>
        {
            // all complete, return to client.
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
            auto.Close();
            wrk.Dispose();
        };

        wrk.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            Start();
        };

        wrk.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public event EventHandler Completed;
    public AutoResetEvent auto = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void Start()
    {
        auto.WaitOne();
        Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    BackgroundWorker wrk = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client clien = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            clien.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(clien_GetDataCompleted);
            clien.GetDataAsync(i);
        }
    }

    public void clien_GetDataCompleted(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            result += e.Result;
            auto.Set();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subscribing multiple (5) times to the GetDataCompleted event, one for each call, so each time the event is getting fired, your handler is getting invoked 5 times (5x5=25). Might want to move this line:

```
clien.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(clien_GetDataCompleted);
```

out of the loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it has fixed the extra calls, but the problem i have now is that in clien_GetDataCompleted the result is incremented, but when Completed gets called the final result variable only holds the last value, any ideas.?

Comment: What's result? How is it being used? That issue is unlikely to be WCF related, I'd say.

Comment: hi tomar, its ok, i have started using the task model from .net 4 instead, thanks for your help.